# Unzip with zlib without using SetCurrentDirectory

Tags: c++, zip

I'm using [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) for unzip list of zip files. Here is the simple way to do it. But `SetCurrentDirectory` function calling affect my other threads. is there any way to unzip to specific directory using zlib.

```
SetCurrentDirectory("c:\\docs\\stuff");
HZIP hz = OpenZip("c:\\stuff.zip",0);
ZIPENTRY ze; GetZipItem(hz,-1,&ze); int numitems=ze.index;
for (int i=0; i<numitems; i++)
{ GetZipItem(hz,i,&ze);
   UnzipItem(hz,i,ze.name);
 }
 CloseZip(hz);
```

Comment: it does not look like zlib. The functions in your example are not present in the manual (http://www.zlib.net/manual.html). I used zlib a lot and never SetCurrentDirectory()

Comment: @cha : This is the exact source file. http://www.openscenegraph.org/svn/osg/OpenSceneGraph/tags/OpenSceneGraph-2.9.7/src/osgPlugins/zip/unzip.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
void unZipPackage(std::wstring zip_file,std::wstring dest_dir){ 

    HZIP hz = OpenZip(zip_file.c_str(),0);  
    ZIPENTRY ze; GetZipItem(hz,-1,&ze); int numitems=ze.index;
    for (int i=0; i<numitems; i++)
    { 
        GetZipItem(hz,i,&ze);               
        wchar_t dest[MAX_PATH];
        swprintf(dest,MAX_PATH,L"%s\\%s",dest_dir.c_str(),ze.name);     
        UnzipItem(hz,i,dest);       
    }   
    CloseZip(hz);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a wrapper allowing easy usage of zlib library. You have tagged the question as a C++, you are using a wrapper for c++, and at the same time you are using the global helper APIs utilising this wrapper.

I recommend you use the TUnzip wrapper directly (see how `UnzipItemInternal` is implemented as an example). The TUnzip class has a nice method allowing to set the base directory `ZRESULT TUnzip::SetUnzipBaseDir(const TCHAR *dir)`. Call it to set the directory

Comment: actually I was unaware this is not zlib. but I cannot change the library because i'm doing some changes on existing project. Anyway It helped your comments to find the answer. thank you.